# list() and mysqli_fetch_row() in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to somehow use `list` and `mysqli_fetch_row` together? The code below doesn't work.

```
$query = "SELECT id, email FROM emails WHERE id='24'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
list($get_id, $get_email) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

This code however works, but I want a code that is less lines:

```
$query = "SELECT id, email FROM emails WHERE id='24'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$get_id = $row[0];
$get_email = $row[1];
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What result did you get?

Comment: Maybe you don't have record with `id = 24`? What shows `var_dump(mysqli_fetch_row($result))`?

Comment: There is record in it, the question is about the list and mysqli_fetch_row functions combined.

Comment: Why do you need to? You can access every column from the $result array directly anyway

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_result`, not actual values.  You can modify your second example to use `list()`, but not your first.

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors (you do have error reporting on, right?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `list()` like that.

So there must be an error in your query or somewhere else in your code, so add this code to be sure if there is an error and if so what it is.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$query = "SELECT id, email FROM emails WHERE id='24'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysqli_error($link);
    exit;
}

list($get_id, $get_email) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```